# How to show operation of calculator in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

So I am building a calculator using only p5.js. I have made it function properly. I would like it to show the whole number sentence like 1 + 1 but when you click '=' it shoulddelete the number sentence and only show the answer. Does anyone know how to make this possible. Help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much for the people that would like to help.

```js
let number = 0;
let number1 = 0;
let operation = "";

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  let one = createButton('1');
  one.mousePressed(clickedOne);
  let two = createButton('2');
  two.mousePressed(clickedTwo);
  let three = createButton('3');
  three.mousePressed(clickedThree);
  let four = createButton('4');
  four.mousePressed(clickedFour);
  let five = createButton('5');
  five.mousePressed(clickedFive);
  let six = createButton('6');
  six.mousePressed(clickedSix);
  let seven = createButton('7');
  seven.mousePressed(clickedSeven);
  let eight = createButton('8');
  eight.mousePressed(clickedEight);
  let nine = createButton('9');
  nine.mousePressed(clickedNine);
  let zero = createButton('0');
  zero.mousePressed(clickedZero);
  let equals = createButton('=');
  equals.mousePressed(pressedEquals);
  let clear = createButton('AC');
  clear.mousePressed(clickedClear);
  let divide = createButton('÷');
  divide.mousePressed(clickedDivide);
  let multiply = createButton('x');
  multiply.mousePressed(clickedMultiply);
  let add = createButton('+');
  add.mousePressed(clickedAdd);
  let minus = createButton('-');
  minus.mousePressed(clickedMinus);
  one.position(100, 150);
  one.size(45, 45);
  two.position(144, 150);
  two.size(45, 45);
  four.position(100, 194);
  four.size(45, 45);
  six.position(188, 194);
  six.size(45, 45);
  three.position(188, 150);
  three.size(45, 45);
  five.position(144, 194);
  five.size(45, 45);
  seven.position(100, 238);
  seven.size(45, 45);
  eight.position(144, 238);
  eight.size(45, 45);
  nine.position(188, 238);
  nine.size(45, 45);
  zero.position(100, 282);
  zero.size(89, 45);
  equals.position(188, 282);
  equals.size(45, 45);
  divide.position(232, 150);
  divide.size(45, 45);
  multiply.position(232, 194);
  multiply.size(45, 45);
  add.position(232, 238);
  add.size(45, 45);
  minus.position(232, 282);
  minus.size(45, 45);
  clear.position(100, 106);
  clear.size(177, 45);

}

function clickedOne() {
  number = number * 10 + 1;
}

function clickedTwo() {
  number = number * 10 + 2;
}

function clickedThree() {
  number = number * 10 + 3;
}

function clickedFour() {
  number = number * 10 + 4;
}

function clickedFive() {
  number = number * 10 + 5;
}

function clickedSix() {
  number = number * 10 + 6;
}

function clickedSeven() {
  number = number * 10 + 7;
}

function clickedEight() {
  number = number * 10 + 8;
}

function clickedNine() {
  number = number * 10 + 9;
}

function clickedZero() {
  number = number * 10 + 0;
}

function clickedDivide() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "÷";
}

function clickedMultiply() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "x";
}

function clickedAdd() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "+";
}

function clickedMinus() {
  number1 = number;
  number = 0;
  operation = "-";
}

function clickedClear() {
  number = 0;
}

function pressedEquals() {
  if (operation === "+") {
        number = number1 + number;
    } else if (operation === "-") {
        number = number1 - number;
    } else if (operation === "x") {
        number = number1 * number
    } if (operation === "÷") {
        number = number1 / number
    }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noStroke();
  fill(20, 255, 255, 30);
  rect(100, 53, 177, 54, 5);
  strokeWeight(6);
  stroke(0);
  noFill();
  rect(97, 50, 183, 280, 5);
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  textSize(25);

  text(number, 110, 100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the operation when `=` is pressed:

```js
function clickedEquals(){
    if (operation == "+") {
        number = number1 + number;
    } else if (operation == "-") {
        number = number1 - number;
    } else if (operation == "x") {
        number = number1 * number;
    } else if (operation == "÷") {
        number = number1 / number;
    }

    operation = ""; // <--- reset
}
```

Concatenate the display text by `number1`, `operation` and `number`, if `operation` is not empty:

```js
function draw() {
    // [...]

    if (operation != "") {
        let display = number1 + " " + operation + " " + number
        text(display, 110, 100);
    } else {
        text(number, 110, 100);
    }
}
```

See the example:

```js
let number1 = 0;    
let number = 0;
let operation = "";
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  let one = createButton('1');
  one.mousePressed(clickedOne);
  let two = createButton('2');
  two.mousePressed(clickedTwo);
  let three = createButton('3');
  three.mousePressed(clickedThree);
  let four = createButton('4');
  four.mousePressed(clickedFour);
  let five = createButton('5');
  five.mousePressed(clickedFive);
  let six = createButton('6');
  six.mousePressed(clickedSix);
  let seven = createButton('7');
  seven.mousePressed(clickedSeven);
  let eight = createButton('8');
  eight.mousePressed(clickedEight);
  let nine = createButton('9');
  nine.mousePressed(clickedNine);
  let zero = createButton('0');
  zero.mousePressed(clickedZero);
  let equals = createButton('=');
  equals.mousePressed(clickedEquals);
  let clear = createButton('AC');
  let divide = createButton('÷');
  divide.mousePressed(clickedDivide);
  let multiply = createButton('x');
  multiply.mousePressed(clickedMultiply);
  let add = createButton('+');
  add.mousePressed(clickedAdd);
  let minus = createButton('-');
  minus.mousePressed(clickedMinus);
  one.position(100, 150);
  one.size(45, 45);
  two.position(144, 150);
  two.size(45, 45);
  four.position(100, 194);
  four.size(45, 45);
  six.position(188, 194);
  six.size(45, 45);
  three.position(188, 150);
  three.size(45, 45);
  five.position(144, 194);
  five.size(45, 45);
  seven.position(100, 238);
  seven.size(45, 45);
  eight.position(144, 238);
  eight.size(45, 45);
  nine.position(188, 238);
  nine.size(45, 45);
  zero.position(100, 282);
  zero.size(89, 45);
  equals.position(188, 282);
  equals.size(45, 45);
  divide.position(232, 150);
  divide.size(45, 45);
  multiply.position(232, 194);
  multiply.size(45, 45);
  add.position(232, 238);
  add.size(45, 45);
  minus.position(232, 282);
  minus.size(45, 45);
  clear.position(100, 106);
  clear.size(177, 45);

}

function clickedOne(){
  number = number * 10 + 1;
}

function clickedTwo(){
  number = number * 10 + 2;
}

function clickedThree(){
  number = number * 10 + 3;
}

function clickedFour(){
  number = number * 10 + 4;
}

function clickedFive(){
  number = number * 10 + 5;
}

function clickedSix(){
  number = number * 10 + 6;
}

function clickedSeven(){
  number = number * 10 + 7;
}

function clickedEight(){
  number = number * 10 + 8;
}

function clickedNine(){
  number = number * 10 + 9;
}

function clickedZero(){
  number = numer * 10 + 0;
}

function clickedAdd(){ 
    number1 = number;
    number = 0;
    operation = "+";
}

function clickedMinus(){ 
    number1 = number;
    number = 0;
    operation = "-";
}

function clickedMultiply(){ 
    number1 = number;
    number = 0;
    operation = "x";
}

function clickedDivide(){ 
    number1 = number;
    number = 0;
    operation = "÷";
}

function clickedEquals(){
    if (operation == "+") {
        number = number1 + number;
    } else if (operation == "-") {
        number = number1 - number;
    } else if (operation == "x") {
        number = number1 * number;
    } else if (operation == "÷") {
        number = number1 / number;
    }
    operation = "";
}

function draw() {
    background(220);
    noStroke();
    fill(20, 255, 255, 30);
    rect(100, 53, 177, 54, 5);
    strokeWeight(6);
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    rect(97, 50, 183, 280, 5);
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke(0);
    fill(0);
    textSize(25);

    if (operation != "") {
        let display = number1 + " " + operation + " " + number
        text(display, 110, 100);
    } else {
        text(number, 110, 100);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```